# fish: Is it possible to swap `right` and `Alt + right` keybinds in autosuggestion?

Tags: fish

In fish autosuggestion, `right` accepts the suggestion completely, and `Alt + right` accepts by words. Since I personally prefer getting suggested by words, I want to swap these two keybindings.

I found that I can change keybinding to `accept-autosuggestion` with `bind` command, but I couldn't find a way to swap these two behaviors.

Is it possible to swap these, and if possible, how can I setup fish so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From one of my old answers:

> No.
>
> Fish's bindings accept the part of the suggestion they move the cursor over - e.g. "forward-word" would move over the next word if that was actually in the commandline, so it accepts the next word of the suggestion.
>
> The exception is "forward-char" (bound to e.g. right-arrow and ctrl-f by default), which accepts the entire suggestion.

To clarify: `forward-char` is *hardcoded* to accept the entire autosuggestion if it moves over the first character of it. See [the source](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/src/reader.cpp#L2863-L2873).

This would require a patch to fish itself.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is create your own custom key bindings that override the default bindings for those keys. Create a file named *~/.config/fish/functions/fish_user_key_bindings.fish* with content similar to this:

```
function fish_user_key_bindings
    bind \e\[C forward-bigword
    bind \e\e\[C forward-char
end
```

I say "similar" because the exact sequence sent by your keys may be different than on my system (but probably is the same). The easiest way to find out what your keys send is with the `fish_key_reader` program. Note that you can find out function is bound to a key by just typing `bind` followed by the key name or sequence of chars it sends but without any action to be performed. If you just type `bind` you'll see all the bindings currently in effect.